# Join 3 or more tables with Comma separated values in Oracle

Tags: oracle, join, listagg

I've 3 tables (One parent and 2 childs) as below

- Student(Parent)

> ```
> StudentID | Name |  Age
>     1     |  AA  |  23
>     2     |  BB  |  25
>     3     |  CC  |  27
> ```

- Book(child 1)

> ```
> BookID    | SID | BookName |  BookPrice
>     1     |  1  |  ABC     |    20
>     2     |  1  |  XYZ     |    15
>     3     |  3  |  LMN     |    34
>     4     |  3  |  DDD     |    90
> ```

- Pen(child 2)

> ```
>  PenID    | SID | PenBrandName |  PenPrice
>     1     |  2  |      LML     |    20
>     2     |  1  |      PARKER  |    15
>     3     |  2  |      CELLO   |    34
>     4     |  3  |      LML     |    90
> ```

I need to join the tables and get an output as Below

> ```
> StudentID | Name |  Age | BookNames  | TotalBookPrice  | PenBrands  | TotalPenPrice
>     1     |  AA  |  23  |  ABC, XYZ  |       35        |   PARKER   |       15 
>     2     |  BB  |  25  |    null    |       00        | LML, CELLO |       54
>     3     |  CC  |  27  |  LMN, DDD  |       124       |   LML      |       90
> ```

This is the code i tried :

```
Select s.studentID as "StudentID", s.name as "Name", s.age as "AGE", 
LISTAGG(b.bookName, ',') within group (order by b.bookID) as "BookNames",
SUM(b.bookPrice) as "TotalBookPrice",
LISTAGG(p.penBrandName, ',') within group (order by p.penID) as "PenBrands",
SUM(p.penPrice) as "TotalPenPrice"
FROM Student s
LEFT JOIN BOOK b ON b.SID = s.StudentID
LEFT JOIN PEN p ON p.SID = s.StudentID
GROUP BY s.studentID, s.name, s.age
```

The result i get has multiple values of Book and Pen (cross product result in multiple values)

```
StudentID | Name |  Age |      BookNames    | TotalBookPrice  |     PenBrands     | TotalPenPrice
    1     |  AA  |  23  |  ABC,ABC,XYZ,XYZ  |       35        |   PARKER,PARKER   |       15
```

Please let me know how to fix this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Two SQL LEFT JOINS produce incorrect result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464037/two-sql-left-joins-produce-incorrect-result)

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]. Please before considering posting read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect research in posts. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of Joining the tables and doing aggregation, You have to aggregate first and then join your tables -

```
Select s.studentID as "StudentID", s.name as "Name", s.age as "AGE", 
"BookNames",
"TotalBookPrice",
"PenBrands",
"TotalPenPrice"
FROM Student s
LEFT JOIN (SELECT SID, LISTAGG(b.bookName, ',') within group (order by b.bookID) as "BookNames", 
                  SUM(b.bookPrice) as "TotalBookPrice"
             FROM BOOK
            GROUP BY SID) b ON b.SID = s.StudentID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT SID, LISTAGG(p.penBrandName, ',') within group (order by p.penID) as "PenBrands", 
                  SUM(p.penPrice) as "TotalPenPrice"
             FROM PEN
            GROUP BY SID) p ON p.SID = s.StudentID;
```

Comment: FYI, that type of design model is known as a Fan Trap.